# Win10: How can I set a background image for the logon screen when the user restarted the computer?

Tags: windows-10, login, desktop-customization, lock-screen

First of all, I do not want to use the lock-screen in Windows 10, but only the logon screen. I already figured out that there are two different logon screens: first, the one displayed when a user logs on for the first time after restarting the computer, and the second that appears when the user logs off from a logged-on user.

While I managed to set a background for the second type of logon-screen by temporarily enabling the lock screen, set a wallpaper, and then disabling the lockscreen using

```
Administrative Templates -> Control Panel -> Personalization -> Do not  display the lock screen
```

I unfortunately fail to set a wallpaper for the "first case" scenario, i.e. the logonscreen displayed after the user restarted the PC. There, I only get the "accent color" as a background, but no image.

My question is simple: how can I set a background image for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This operation has become pretty simple since the Windows 10 Anniversary Update:

- In *Settings > Personalization > Lock screen*, enable
  *Show lock screen background picture on the sign-in screen*.

  [image]
- Under *Background*, click on the default "Windows spotlight" which shows a
  changing selection of images from Microsoft and select instead "Picture" or
  "Slideshow" to choose your own preferred background image.

  [image]

The image you select here will appear as both your lock screen background and sign-in screen background.